# Setting column specific user privileges on a database for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a portal for a school where the teachers could enter the marks of the students and even monitor the performance of the respective class they are teaching. The structure of my database is as follows:

One table for each class(division) with fields,

`Name` `Roll_no` `Total-Marks` `Subject1` `Subject2`...

Query_1: Now, if there is a teacher who teaches class X-A the subject `Subject1`, say. How can i create a user name for the teacher and restrict her to be able to make changes only to the column `Subject1`?

Query_2: The teacher should be able to log into the database from any address with her desired user name and password.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
Well you could have a permissions table and every time a teacher accesses a table you can check there if they are allowed.

Q2:
select * from TeacherTable where username='username' and password='password'

I suppose you have in interface and if you say from anywhere I will suppose is a web interface so it should be quite easy to implement.

Comment: But, primarily, how do i alter the permissions? The grant statement is what i'm hitting at.

Comment: if it were me I would make a table with two columns: 1 with the id of the teacher and one with the id of the class/subject/permission and I would add a join or where statement (depending on how you are used. I use join) in witch I would check to see if the teacher has permission to modify/add grades on that subject. As for altering permissions just do an admin panel where someone can add remove permissions. When someone adds a permission add a new entry in the permission table and when someone removes a permission remove the entry from the permission table. Hope it helps.

Comment: If you can't figure it out please tell me and I will try to write you a short example.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I designed my database in a rather untidy manner. Well, i've created multiple login id's for all the teachers and given them selective/limited permissions. I'm still using the lone table for each class. Apart from this i've only added another table that holds the data for teachers, that is the subject a particular username is teaching(with class).